# Обязателен ли вызов forceLoad и deliverResult в AsyncTaskLoader

Tags: java, android, android-loader

У меня есть `AsyncTaskLoader` в котором реализован только конструктор и метод `doInBackground`. При вызове:

```
mLoadData = getSupportLoaderManager().initLoader(LOADER_ID, bundle, this);
mLoadData.onContentChanged();
```

вызывается только конструктор! Но если добавить:

```
@Override
    public void forceLoad() {
        Log.i(TAG, MSG + "forceLoad");
        super.forceLoad();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStartLoading() {
        super.onStartLoading();
        Log.i(TAG, MSG + "onStartLoading");
        forceLoad();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStopLoading() {
        super.onStopLoading();
        Log.i(TAG, MSG + "onStopLoading");
    }

    @Override
    public void deliverResult(ArrayList<ArrayList<ArrayList<String>>> list) {
        Log.i(TAG, MSG + "deliverResult");
        super.deliverResult(list);
    }
```

Сразу все начинает работать (я про `loadInBAckground`)! Выходит они обязательны?

Comment: Ну так вы ж, вроде, `forceLoad` то не вызвали вот он и не вызвался (соответственно запустив задачу)?...

Comment: @ЮрийСПб, т.е. он необходим?

Comment: Насколько я понял - нет. Надо только его вызывать. Т.е. переопределять не надо.

Comment: @ЮрийСПб, ну тогда закиньте это в ответ! :D

Comment: Ну, я ж не пробовал... Вот вы пробовали и у вас заработало?.. Если да, то напишу в ответ.

Comment: @ЮрийСПб, вот после тренировки попробую и Вы напишите в ответ :).

Comment: @ЮрийСПб, Вы были правы. Без переопределения работает.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Переопределение методов не требуется. Надо лишь не забыть вызвать `forceLoad` после инициализации лоадера.